# change value in row of dataframe on condition

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe  with certain values and want to exchange values in one row on a condition. If the value is greater than x I want it to change to zero. I tried with .loc but somehow I get a Keyerror everytime I try. Does .loc work to select rows instead of columns? I used it for columns before, but I cant get it to work for rows.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(4), 'b': np.random.randn(4), 'c': np.random.randn(4)})
print(df)
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
df.loc[(df['Total'] < x), ['Total']] = 0
```

I also tried using iloc, but get another error. I dont think its a complex problem, but im kind of stuck, so help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign values with `loc` - first set rows for repalce values by string - here `Total`, because set row label `Total` and then compare values of this rows selected by `loc` - It return boolean mask:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(4), 'b': np.random.randn(4), 'c': np.random.randn(4)})
print(df)
          a         b         c
0 -0.217679 -0.361865 -0.235634
1  0.821455  0.685609  0.953490
2  1.481278  0.573761 -1.689625
3  1.331864  0.287728 -0.344943

df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()


x = 1
df.loc['Total', df.loc['Total'] < x] = 0
print (df)
              a         b         c
0     -0.217679 -0.361865 -0.235634
1      0.821455  0.685609  0.953490
2      1.481278  0.573761 -1.689625
3      1.331864  0.287728 -0.344943
Total  3.416918  1.185233  0.000000
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.loc['Total'] < x)
a    False
b    False
c     True
Name: Total, dtype: bool
```